# Issue connecting to SQL Server using SQL Alias

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I created an SQL Alias:

```
Name: CIHDB
Server: SQLSRV
Protocol: tcp
Port no: (empty)
```

My connection string within Visual Studio says:

`Data Source=CIHDB;Initial Catalog=CIH;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework`

But that fails with the error: `TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

When I change the "Data Source" in the connection string to "localhost," I connect with no problem.

I am thinking that I am using the wrong protocol in the Alias.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I used both

`cliconfg.exe`

and

`c:\windows\syswow64\cliconfg.exe`

(64 and 32 bit versions of cliconfg.exe)

I saw that tcp/ip was not enabled and so once I fixed that, all fell into place.